# Discord.py ping user who inputted message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've made a command that prompts the server with 2 numbers, and the users add the numbers in the shortest time possible. I'm trying to figure out a way to ping the user who got the correct answer, but I can't seem to get it to work. One thing I've tried applying is adding `m.author == message.author` to the return line, as seen [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#waiting-for-events), but I get an error saying message is undefined. I'm still pretty new to this, so it'd be nice to know how to implement it into my code, or if there's a different way, as all I want is to be able to have the bot ping the user who sent the right answer first.

````
@client.command()
async def math(ctx):
    num_one = random.randint(1, 98)
    num_two = randint(1, 98)
    answer = num_one + num_two
    answer_string = str(answer)
    await ctx.send(f'{num_one} + {num_two}?')
    def check(m):
        return m.content == answer_string
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send(f"got the correct answer!")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do `await ctx.send(f"{msg.author.mention} got the correct answer!")`.

[client.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) returns a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message) object, which means it has an author attribute. You can then use the .mention attribute of a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Member) object(the author), which will ping them.